# Retrieve the access token, secret access key and session token from aws cognito

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

```
    AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
      IdentityPoolId: 'us-east-1:2ce7b2c2-898f-4a26-9066-d4feff8ebfe4'
  });

  // Make the call to obtain credentials
  AWS.config.credentials.get(function(){

      // Credentials will be available when this function is called.
      var accessKeyId = AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId;
      var secretAccessKey = AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey;
      var sessionToken = AWS.config.credentials.sessionToken;
      //var identityId = AWS.config.credentials.identityId;

      return res.send({
        accessKeyId: accessKeyId
      });

  });
```

All of the variables have null value. Why? What am i doing wrong? Is there another way to access it?

Also i am supposed to send a secretkey and token to retrieve a session key

**UPDATE:**

When i try this method, I get an error saying:
**Error: NotAuthorizedException: Unauthenticated access is not supported for this identity pool.**

```
AWS.config.credentials.get(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error: "+err);
        return;
    }
    console.log("Cognito Identity Id: " + AWS.config.credentials.identityId);

    // Other service clients will automatically use the Cognito Credentials provider
    // configured in the JavaScript SDK.
    var cognitoSyncClient = new AWS.CognitoSync();
    cognitoSyncClient.listDatasets({
        IdentityId: AWS.config.credentials.identityId,
        IdentityPoolId: ""
    }, function(err, data) {
        if ( !err ) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
        return res.send({
          data: data
        });
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception you are seeing means that you have not set up your identity pool to allow unauthenticated identities.

You are not passing any logins in the logins map when you call get credentials, which means your user is un authenticated (which is not allowed by your identity pool).

Here is some documentation describing how to authenticate using external identity providers:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/external-identity-providers.html

Comment: Thanks! i had to check allow unauthenticated connections in the aws console settings.